# How do I set AWS SNS message attribute values with spring-cloud-aws-messaging or aws-java-sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sns, spring-cloud-aws

I have a standard SNS topic and I´ve set the "subscription filter policy" like this:

```
{
  "event": [
    "eventName"
  ]
}
```

When I publish a message through the AWS console using the attributes message, the message goes to the right SQS subscriber. So the subscription filter worked just fine.

Now I'm trying to do the same on my java code (Spring Boot).

I'm using the lib `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` which I understand is just a Wrapper of AWS JDK.

The problem is I can't figured out how to set the message attributes just like I did on AWS console.

Doesn´t matter the JSON format I sent to SNS the attributes always are in the body of the SNS message. I guess there is a specific method to set those attributes.

I found `com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.MessageAttributeValue`

I'm not sure if is the right class, also I couldn't understand how to publish the message and the attributes as the method publish doesn't accept it .

```
this.amazonSNS.publish(this.snsTopicARN, message, messageAttributes ???);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to official documentation, there is MessageAttributeValue.Builder, which matches what you need.

https://javadoc.io/static/software.amazon.awssdk/sns/2.10.37/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sns/model/MessageAttributeValue.Builder.html

```
Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<>();

attributes.put("event", MessageAttributeValue.builder()
        .dataType("String")
        .stringValue("eventName")
        .build());

PublishRequest request = PublishRequest.builder()
        .topicArn("yourTopic")
        .message("YourMessageBody")
        .messageAttributes(attributes)
        .build();

yourDefinedSnsClient.publish(request);
```

Comment: I changed from spring-cloud-aws to aws-java-sdk and did like you said. it works fine. tks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use spring-cloud-aws you can do something like this:

```
SnsMessage snsMessage = SnsMessage.builder()
    .message("test")
    .build();

Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("event", "eventName");

this.notificationMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(topicName, snsMessage, headers);
```

Comment: This only works when your filter policy scope is set to "Message Attributes." This does not work if your filter policy scope is set to "Message Body."

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use attribute-based message filtering, and switch to payload-based message filtering, you can too. You simply have to set a subscription attribute named `FilterPolicyScope` to `MessageBody`, whereas the default is `MessageAttributes`. More info: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/